# powershell new-item creates a new file for every line

Tags: javascript, powershell

In my script i work with javascript files and i use out-file to write files to a new location:

```
myFile.js | cat | browserify | uglifyjs | Out-File ..\build\myFile.js -encoding UTF8
```

This will output 1 file with an UTF8 encoding instead of UTF2.

I would like use new-Item because it would create folders if not existant, and i would not have to set the encoding. But i have a problem. This command:

```
 myFile.js | cat | browserify | uglifyjs | new-item ..\build\myFile.js -type file -force
```

will output a bunch of files ( i think based on new-lines ) ?

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        15.01.2014     12:19      32069 myFile.js
-a---        15.01.2014     12:19      32255 myFile.js
-a---        15.01.2014     12:19      32007 myFile.js
-a---        15.01.2014     12:19      32008 myFile.js
-a---        15.01.2014     12:19      32697 myFile.js
-a---        15.01.2014     12:19      32001 myFile.js
-a---        15.01.2014     12:19       7429 myFile.js
```

What am i missing? i would like to output the contents to a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
(myFile.js | cat | browserify | uglifyjs) | out-string | new-item ..\build\myFile.js -type file -force
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding brackets before piping to the file.  I've not seen the syntax where you pipe to cat before, so I have swapped that around so it becomes `cat myFile.js`

```
(cat myFile.js | browserify | uglifyjs) | new-item ..\build\myFile.js -type file -force
```

Comment: This will still produce a file for every line in my script. But i like the style :)